# JS/JQ for between div and screenY during scrolling document

Tags: javascript

i want javascript or Jquery function return me that >>> how div far from screenY , when i make scrolling to the document;

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a small demo for this.

Please check it here.

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/codebombs/4sMKW/

Check in Console, in the above demo for screenY position of the DIV.

Here I am using this code :

```
//When document is scrolled
$(document).scroll(function(e) {
    //Get div's y position relative to viewport.
    var y = $('div').offset().top - $('body').scrollTop();
    //Show value in console
    console.log ( y );
});
```

Let me know if this helped and also if it need any modifications.